# Is there any way where user can set the custom desired price greater than zero and proceed to cart for any product?

Tags: price, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, custom-prices

I am trying something for a social cause website where there are trying to provide a user choice price for a NGO's product which can be any price.
this is for promotional activity where user can set the any price for product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, this blog post (German) uses exactly this as a simplified example for dynamic pricing: http://www.avs-webentwicklung.de/nc/blog/artikel/magento-umsetzung-von-flexiblen-preisen.html

### Summary:

1. Add an input field "price" to the form on the product page.
2. Create a custom module with an observer for `catalog_product_get_final_price`:

   ```
   <events>
       <catalog_product_get_final_price>
           <observers>
               <modulename_catalog_product_get_final_price>
                   <type>singleton</type>
                   <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                   <method>getFinalPrice</method>
               </modulename_catalog_product_get_final_price>
           </observers>
       </catalog_product_get_final_price>
   </events>
   ```
3. In the observer, set the final price based on the request:

   ```
   /**
    * Update price for product items
    *
    * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
    */
   public function getFinalPrice($observer) {

       /* @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
       $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

       if ($buyRequest = $product->getCustomOption('info_buyRequest')) {

           $buyRequest = unserialize($buyRequest->getValue());

           if (is_array($buyRequest) && isset($buyRequest['price'])) {

               $product->setFinalPrice(floatval($buyRequest['price']));
           }
       }
   }
   ```

(this example does not validate the price to be greater than zero, I'll leave that part as an exercise to the reader)

Answer (score 1):

You even don't need coding. Depending on the range of chooseable prices, you can just use custom options with a price.